# How the user will able to login their application either using facebook account or google account or wso2 account

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Suggest me some process which i follow to complete my task. I am new in using wso2.

1) How the user will able to login in their application either using facebook account or google account or wso2 account using wso2 identity server.

2) And there is one more condition some user login based on resources(link buildings).
for that resource user will able to login with single sign on using wso2 identity server.

Answer (score 0):

Step 01: You can setup federated authentication as per [1]. Do it for both Facebook and Google.

Step 02: Configure multiple options from advance authentication configuration. Once you complete Step 01 pls get back to explain Step 02.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+Federated+Authentication